# what's the 'Int -> Int' type ? when a function as a return value?

Tags: ios, swift

```
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int ->Int) {
    func addOne(number:Int) ->Int {
          return 1 + number
    }
    return addOne // result`enter code here`:Int -> Int
}
var increment = makeIncrementer() // result:`enter code here`Int -> Int
increment(7) // result`enter code here`8
```

- I can't understand it how to implement ！

Comment: That function returns function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In swift a function can return another function.

The following statement:

```
func makeIncrementer() -> (Int ->Int)
```

means the `makeIncrement` function will return another function which has an argument type of `Int` and it returns an `Int`

In the above case, the `makeIncrementer` function returns the `addOne` function and then you are calling it by passing a value of 7. (It is somewhat similar a function that returns a function pointer in C language)

You can read more about these kind of functions here : [Function Types as Return Types](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html)